# Updating properties of an object in React with useState

Tags: reactjs, state, javascript-objects, use-state

I have this state:

```
  const [test, setTest] = useState({
    test1: "test",
    test2: "test",
    test3: "test",
  });

useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setTest({
        ...test,
        test1: "test1",
      });
    }, 2000);

    setTimeout(() => {
      setTest({
        ...test,
        test2: "test2",
      });
    }, 3000);
  }, []);
```

and I want to get something like:

```
{
  test1: "test1"
  test2: "test2"
  test3: "test"
}
```

but I get:

```
{
  test1: "test"
  test2: "test2"
  test3: "test"
}
```

Is that possible?
What I am doing wrong? Thx

I need to keep this object form, I'm working with APIs and I don't want to have 30 different useStates for each API. I just want to have all fetch API data in one object and use it as a prop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a callback instead, so you have the most up-to-date reference to the current `test` in state, instead of having only a reference to the original (unmodified) `test` from the initial mount:

```
setTest(test => ({
    ...test,
    test2: "test2",
}));
```